# AWS Cloudfront 504 when POST update with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Cloudflare gives a 504 when we update our products on the wordpress backend, It works fine for Mutli-language pages but english (root) gives a 504 pretty much every time. The 1 time i got it to update it gave a 302.

We go CF - ALB to EC2 server. All HTTPS and port 443.
Example error: 
[image: CF Error]

CF settings for wp-admin/* 
[image]

Everything worked well with CloudFlare since we moved CloudFront we have had this error.

Comment: What do the logs on your server indicate?

Comment: it was a 499 error (nginx error code) CF was closing the connection after 60 seconds the post request takes 1.6mins got to love wordpress and to many plugins

Answer (score 1):

it was a 499 error (nginx error code) CF was closing the connection after 60 seconds the post request takes 1.6mins got to love wordpress and to many plugins

I asked AWS to extend my origin time out to 120 seconds